# Change title and subtitle of ListTile in flutter using a AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, async-await, listtile, reorderable-list

I am building an app and am new to Flutter. The App is supposed to take an input via TextFormField and used that Data to build tiles in a List of ListTile Widget. That works. Now I want to use the trailing Icon of the ListTiles and the onPressed() function to display an AlertDialog to edit the title and subtitel of each ListTile. And here is the Problem. I may have coded myself into a corner there. Can someone pls tell me how can I reference the right widget and change its properties. I do it very laborious with all the arguments given in the functions and by deleting an tile and inserting a new at the same index of the list - There i cant setState() so it only updates with the next action that does update the state. And when I do delete a tile from the list and want to reference the new inserted Listtile the async function throws an error "This BuildContext is no longer valid".

I need dire help

Here is the ListTile expansion

```
ListTile _tile(number, String title, String subtitle, IconData icon, context,
    cont1, cont2, height, width, indexcolor) {
  return ListTile(
    key: ValueKey("$number-$title-$subtitle"),
    tileColor: indexcolor.isOdd
        ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 217, 218, 247)
        : Colors.white,
    title: Text(title,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 20,
        )),
    subtitle: Text(subtitle),
    leading: Icon(
      icon,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      onPressed: () async {
        await showEditDialog(context, cont1, cont2, height, width, title,
            subtitle, number, listTiles, height, width);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

and here is the function that returns the AlertDialog

```
Future<void> showEditDialog(BuildContext context, cont1, cont2, height, width,
    String titel, String subs, number, listofTiles, heightSrc, widthScr) async {
  return await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: SizedBox(
          height: height * .25,
          width: width * .9,
          child: Column(children: [
            const Text("Edit Task",
                style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 140, 184))),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: cont1,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: titel,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 231, 231)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: cont2,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: subs,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 231, 231)),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    cont1.clear();
                    cont2.clear();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text("Cancel"),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  listofTiles.removeAt(number);
                  listofTiles.insert(
                      number,
                      _tile(
                          listTiles.length,
                          cont1.text,
                          cont2.text,
                          Icons.work,
                          context,
                          cont1,
                          cont2,
                          heightSrc,
                          widthScr,
                          (listTiles.length + 1)));
                  cont1.clear();
                  cont2.clear();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  print(listofTiles);
                  setState() {}
                  ;
                },
                child: const Text("Save Changes"),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

and i am using a statefulwidget and here inside of a Scaffold, Column sits this code for the Reordablelist

```
Expanded(
          child: ReorderableListView(
              onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    // titelWid = listChildren[oldIndex].titel.data;
                    if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                      newIndex -= 1;
                    }
                    final item = listTiles.removeAt(oldIndex);
                    listTiles.insert(newIndex, item);
                  },
                );
              },
              children: listTiles),
```

So i tried to use key to reference the ListTile directly, but i did know how to call it and get the infos from the ListTile, so I dont have to drag everything through all the functions.

Can someone pls help
Thanks you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To update the dialog Ui, you can use `StatefulBuilder`.

```dart
  return await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) =>  //this `setState` will update the dialog ui,
          AlertDialog(
```

Sample snippet

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    int c = 0;
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  c++;
                });
              },
              child: Text("value $c")),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you! But could you also answer how to reference a widget, that i want to remove in my code?

Comment: you like to create new widget for dialog content ?

Comment: not exaclty, i want to change titel and subtitel of the ListTiles or if the user wants that, want to delete the ListTile usind the Alert Dialog. For this to happen i need to know what ListTile to delete or to change. My question is how to do that

Comment: updating the ui & changing visibility on dialog?

Comment: could you provide me with a code example? thank you!

Comment: u[dated with sample snippet

Comment: well i think i will need to restructure my code at all, thank you anyway